# ¿Para qué se usa el símbolo -> en PHP?

Tags: php

Soy novato en PHP Solo quiero preguntar de como funciona los signos de comparacion en variables.

Ej:

```
$conexion->conect_errno;
```

Ese -> para que sirve?
Claro indica que es menor.
Pero no entiendo por que aparece indicando de esa manera
(Por que la manera en la que yo uso es: Mysqli_connect(bla...)).
No solo hablo de la conexion sino de todas manera que se ocuoan asi

Comment: Estudia las clases y objetos en php y entenderás eso. No es operador de comparación es un operador flecha, es diferente.

Comment: Es para acceder a métodos y propiedades de una clase por medio del objeto que instanciaste de X clase

Comment: Estudia sobre POO en PHP

Comment: GRACIASSS!!!!!a

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### TLDR;

En PHP, **`->` es un operador de objeto**. Su nombre en el entorno del lenguaje es [`T_OBJECT_OPERATOR`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php). Y se usa para acceder a las propiedades y métodos de los objetos. Es algo que verás siempre que uses POO: `$unObjeto->unMetodo()` o bien `$unObjeto->unaPropiedad`, o bien, cuando estés dentro del ámbito del objeto: `$this->unMetodo()`...

Lo otro que refieres son funciones tradicionales de PHP, como cualquier otra de las que sueles utilizar a diario.

---

Creo que hace falta una acotación con respecto a los ejemplos de código que indicas en la pregunta y que podría ser complemento a tu duda.

La API mysqli, que sirve para gestionar la conexión a la base de datos, las consultas, la obtención de datos, etc, **tiene una [interfaz dual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php)**:

1. La interfaz procedimental.

   En la cual se usan funciones, al estilo tradicional de PHP.

   Por ejemplo:

   ```
   $mysqli=mysqli_connect(...);
   mysqli_query(...);
   mysqli_fetch_assoc(...);
   mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli);

   #etc
   ```
2. El estilo orientado a objetos.

   En la cual se usa la notación `$objeto->metodo()` o bien `$objeto->propiedad`.

   Por ejemplo:

   ```
   #La conexión es particular, se usa new porque MySQLi en realidad es una clase
   $mysqli=new mysqli(...);

   $mysqli->query(...);
   $objeto->fetch_assoc(...);
   $mysqli->affected_rows;

   #etc
   ```

Tú puedes usar cualquiera de las dos, e incluso podrías mezclarlas. Sin embargo ésto no es recomendable, por motivos de claridad en el código.

Aunque el Manual de PHP dice que para quienes vienen de la vieja extensión `mysql_` usar la interfaz procedimental es más fácil, yo particularmente recomiendo usar la interfaz orientada a objetos, porque primeramente no es tan complicado entenderla, es menos verbosa y es más adaptada a los tiempos modernos. Además, los ejemplos del Manual son bastante claros. Siempre que estudies cualquier función de la API verás ejemplos basados en las dos interfaces de programación: procedimental y orientada a objetos.

Aquí hay un ejemplo concreto, con respecto al [método `prepare()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php). El Manual pone siempre en primer lugar el estilo orientado a objetos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en segundo término pone el estilo procedural:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]