# No esta leyendo el archivo de la clase

Tags: php

Tengo un archivo clase plan y quiero utilizar el método listar planes y en el otro archivo lo incluyo y no me deja utilizar el método.

```php
<?php

    Class planes{
        public $id;
        public $titulo;
        public $descripcion;
        public $precio;
        public $profesor;
    
        public function __construct(){
     
        }
    
        public function listar_planes($profesor)
        {
            include '../DataBase/Conexion.php';
            $this->profesor = $profesor;
            $con = new Conexion();
            $data = $Conexion->querySQL("SELECT * FROM `planes` WHERE `profesor` = $this- 
            >profesor");
            $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
            return $data;
        }
}
?>
```

listarplanes.php

```php
    <body> 
         <?php
            require '../php/classPlanes.php';
            $plan = new Planes();
            $data =  $plan.listar_planes($profesor);
       
            foreach ($data as $valor){
                echo $data['id'];
                echo $data['titulo'];
                echo $data['descripcion'];
                echo $data['precio'];
                echo $data['profesor'];
            }
        ?>
    </body>
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar, muchas gracias :D:D

Comment: Puede que la ruta de tu archivo este mal... Cual es la ruta de tu proyecto?... Además, recuerda que cuando imprima, el body estará en el índex o sea, la raíz, claro si no esta en una pagina interna dentro de otra carpeta

Comment: Esto está mal: `$data = $plan.listar_planes($profesor);` Debe ser con [flecha](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/433427/80870) en vez de punto: `$data = $plan->listar_planes($profesor);`